# Repeated 'AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute' in Discord.py Bot

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

I'm working on a Discord bot using discord.py, but I'm encountering a recurring error that I can't seem to resolve. The error occurs in multiple instances and relates to 'NoneType' objects not having certain attributes.

**Error Details:**
I keep getting `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'`, `'get_role'`, and `'members'` in different parts of my code. Here's an example of the error output:

```php
_ClientEventTask exception was never retrieved
future: <ClientEventTask state=finished event=on_ready coro=<bound method ...> exception=AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'")>
...
```

**Context:**
The errors seem to be related to the `self.guild` and `self.stdout` attributes in my bot class, which appear to be `None` when accessed. This leads to the `AttributeError` when I attempt to call methods like `get_role` or `send` on these objects.

**Attempts to Resolve:**

- I've followed a video tutorial exactly to set up the bot, but the error persists.
- I've checked my code for any obvious mistakes in defining or assigning self.guild and self.stdout.

Despite these efforts, I'm unable to figure out why these attributes are None and how to correctly initialize them.

**Questions:**

1. Why are self.guild and self.stdout evaluated as None, and how should they be properly initialized in discord.py?
2. What are the best practices to handle such AttributeError issues in a Discord bot?

Any help in understanding and resolving these errors would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where's your code? Hard to debug a summary of it.

Comment: One debug technique is to find the places where self.guild is assigned and put `assert self.guild is not None` right afterwards. Find where the None comes from and you are closer to a fix. You could even make it a property and check none assignment there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### self.guild is None

You defined `self.guild` as `None` and that's the reason why you get the `NoneType` error. The self.guild should be a guild object I think, but it isn't. None has no attributes like `get_role()` or something, because its empty and not a discord guild.

---

### self.stdout doesn't exist

I read your code and can't find it anywhere. Because its not in your code, you can't use it as variable, you need to define it.